# Extjs Extensible Calendar data[M.EndDate.name] is undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, calendar, extensible

I'm working with Extensible Calendar and trying to make a Custom ajax Store work with this , but I get this error when the Store Load
[image]

so the Calendar does not show the date, here's some code

```
Ext.apply(Extensible.calendar.data.EventMappings, {

        StartDate:   {name: 'fecha_reservacion', mapping: 'fecha_reservacion', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c'},

    });
 Extensible.calendar.data.EventModel.reconfigure();

var eventStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

        fields: [
            {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'fecha_reservacion', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c'},
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/reservacion/get',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'

            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
});

Ext.create('Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel', {
        eventStore: eventStore,
        calendarStore: calendarStore,
        renderTo: 'content',
        title: 'Custom Event Mappings',
        width: 800,
        height: 700,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is wrong `name: 'fecha_reservacion'` should be `name: 'StartDate'`

```
Ext.apply(Extensible.calendar.data.EventMappings, {
    StartDate:   {name: 'fecha_reservacion', mapping: 'fecha_reservacion', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c'},
    // add here all your fields 
});
```

and you have to add the mappings for the other fields too.